# Limit access to a database to a few users. (MS Access 2007)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I would appreciate if someone would help me with this.

I am new to Access and my boss has given me a project to create a tool for our team (I work in insurance). I'm done with most part of the project, but my boss wants editing and updating of database restricted to a few members of our team (yes more than one person can modify) but since the tool is to be used for a wide range of purposes, she would like that the rest of the department (50+ people) can only access certain forms which have buttons etc. that do the job.

So far in this database I have, 3 linked tables (which hold all the data), queries, reports, union queries and make tables and 3 forms. What I would like is for most people to only view forms and use it in form view only, but 4 members of my team to do whatever they want since they need to constantly edit the data.

Does anyone have a hint about where I should begin? Programming is not my cup of tea so I would really appreciate some reference etc. or any help!

Comment: Do you need a security strategy which prevents unprivileged users from changing stored data and which even a determined sophisticated user can not circumvent?  Or can you settle for some form of security which makes it inconvenient for such a user to do what you don't want them to do?

Comment: I would have to say the former. I only want a few (3-4) users having administrator like privileges - have them do whatever they want. But for the rest all I want them to is to login, which would then take them to a form I have set for them and run queries/reports through buttons I have on the form. I don't want them seeing and/or editing tables etc.

Comment: Then you must use the db engine to enforce that level of security.  Security measures you implement at the application level (VBA, form properties, etc.) can all be easily defeated.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: If you want to continue to use Access for data storage, use an MDB  to hold the data.  Then you can set up ULS (user-level security) to grant the appropriate rights to your user groups.  MS removed ULS support from the ACCDB database format, but Access versions >= 2007 can still use MDB format which continues to support ULS.

Comment: But supposedly even ULS can be defeated using password-crackers.  Your only recourse for "bullet-proof" security is to move the data to a db server.  Your front-end Access application would link to server tables and you enforce user privileges at the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you hit file, then hit options, and then select current database, you can force a specific form to pop up whenever you open the access database. In addition, you can take away the user's ability to go through the entire database's content. you can also take away the navigation bar and menus and such. I have been doing this for a while, so here's some advice. Have a main menu form that has a button for every form in the access file. When the user opens the database, he or she should see that main menu form. From there, they can click on the button that will lead them to the form that will solve the needs they have.

Stackoverflow won't let me post a comment, so here is what I was going to say. For those who you want to have access to it, you can have them hold shift while opening the database. If they do that, they will open the database like they were an "admin" to the database. They would be able to edit it however they would like if they hold down shift.

Comment: But wouldn't that hide it for everyone though? I wan't a few people to have access like myself.

p.s With such an approach can't the users repeat the steps you mentioned themselves and unhide etc. everything?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this via a table, assigning users a specific "Security Level" and checking their security level via a login screen.  I then hide the login screen (not close it) so that anytime a form is open it can do a DLookup of the user's security level and then determine if the user has read, write or read/write access to the form.  I can also hide buttons on the form based on the same logic.

Starting in 2007, Access removed their native security, which was pretty inefficient anyway.

Comment: I am using Access 2007! 

But I was thinking along the same lines as you mentioned. I created a table with usernames and password and a yes/no field titled 'IsAdmin'. Using DLookup I can determine if a person is admin and thereby assign access to them. However I am having trouble writing the code for this. Adding the following in the login button didn't help

Me.AllowEdits = DLookup("IsAdmin", "RATusers", "[UserID]=" & Me.cboUser.Value)

Any thoughts?

Comment: That SHOULD work.  Have you checked to make sure Me.cboUser.Value returns what you expect?  Another option would be to try an If/Then/Else like: xxAdmin = DLookup("IsAdmin", "RATusers", "[UserID]=" & Me.cboUser.Value).  Then do an If/Then/Else like: If xxAdmin = -1 Then Me.AllowEdits = True Else Me.AllowEdits = False EndIf.  When I did it, I actually set the Enabled property of all the objects to either True or False, but both options are viable.

Comment: How can I check that? I know it works since cboUser is the combo box on the login screen and I am able to correctly login using the dropdown. Should I used the IF statement within the login command button where the code is also checking for valid username/pw combination or should I input that in the event handler of the login form? For e.g Form_Current() If xxAdmin.....    ?

Comment: Stick a breakpoint in the code and then hover over the piece that says Me.cboUser.Value and see what pops up.  Alternatively, you can put a messagebox in the code that just has the value of Me.cboUser.Value in it, and that will tell you what it thinks it is too.  As for where it goes, I'm guessing it would be in the Load event of each form?

Comment: How can I paste my code here? I guess that might help you see it?